# Sorting selection results using a bound parameter in sqlite with the C/C++ API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, sqlite

I'm wondering if it's possible to parameterize the sort column in sqlite.

I'd like to prepare a single sqlite3_stmt like this (omitting checking the return codes for simplicity's sake).

```
sqlite3_stmt* the_statement;
const char *sql = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table1 WHERE column4 = ? ORDER BY ? ASC"
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &the_statement, NULL)
```

and use it like this

```
sqlite3_bind_int(the_statement, 1, 1);
sqlite3_bind_int(the_statement, 2, COLUMN_TO_SORT_BY);  
while (sqlite3_step(the_statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
    //Do something with each row.  
}
sqlite3_reset()
```

When I execute this code changing the value of COLUMN_TO_SORT_BY from 1 to 3 my results are always returned in the same order (I think the order they are stored in the table, but it could also be as sorted by column1).

So, my question is:  Can you parameterize the ORDER BY argument in a sqlite expression when using the C API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the value you pass in is being treated as an expression, which evaluates to a fixed value - '1' in the first case, '3' in the second.  You could compose a CASE statement to order by, but it could get unwieldy quickly.  Perhaps something like:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE ?
    WHEN 1 THEN column1
    WHEN 2 THEN column2
    WHEN 3 THEN column3
    END
```

Comment: Thanks Martin.  This solved my problem.  It does seem a little bit unwieldy if you have a lot of columns but it will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE ... END` expression isn't necessary, since the [SQLite SELECT docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) mention:

> If the ORDER BY expression is a
>   constant integer K then the expression
>   is considered an alias for the K-th
>   column of the result set (columns are
>   numbered from left to right starting
>   with 1).

So simply use the following statement:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM sometable ORDER BY ?
```

And bind the column index:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, col_index);
```